Cannot delete GCP config controller
Very often my config controller (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/enterprise/config-controller/docs/overview) instances become zombies. See below:
gcloud anthos config controller list
NAME        LOCATION     STATE
trash-kcc3  us-central1
trash-kcc2  us-central1
trash-kcc   us-central1

If I try to delete any of them, it just times out after ~15m.
gcloud anthos config controller delete trash-kcc3 --location=us-central1
You are about to delete instance [trash-kcc3]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Delete request issued for: [trash-kcc3]
Waiting for operation [projects/trash-362115/locations/us-central1/operations/operation-1717404123823-619f84ebc7b99-cf9
78d3b-4809a731] to complete...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.anthos.config.controller.delete) Operation https://krmapihosting.googleapis.com/v1/projects/trash-362115/locations/us-central1/operations/operation-1717404123823-619f84ebc7b99-cf978d3b-4809a731 has not finished in 1800 seconds. The operations may still be underway remotely and may still succeed; use gcloud list and describe commands or https://console.developers.google.com/ to check resource state.

Sometimes, they get deleted. Sometimes, they just stop running (as in the case of the 3 instances listed). Sometimes, I stop being charged by them; sometimes, I do not. And these are not exactly cheap (~$50/month).
When I am charged, one of the clusters is usually visible in the UI (https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list/overview). Right now, trash-kcc is visible, but trash-kcc2 and trash-kcc3 are not.
Any suggestions?
